# What do I need to modify in order to draw this generated maze?

Tags: java, libgdx

Maze class: https://gist.github.com/gamblore/5945328

```
for(MazeEdge edge : mazeEdges) {
    shapeRenderer.line(edge.sX, edge.sY, edge.eX, edge.eY);
}
```

Received Effect:

[image]

Desired Effect:

```
Maze:  _ _ _ _ _ _
Maze: |_  |___   _|
Maze: |     |  ___|
Maze: |_|_|_   _  |
Maze: |_   ___|_  |
Maze: |    _| |_  |
Maze: |_|___|_____|
```

Although take the desired effect as graphical.

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.

Answer (score 0):

Disclaimer, I did not study the code very well and I'm not very familiar with bit operator (&).

`sX`, `sY`, `eX` and `eY` don't seem wall coordinates to me. They represent edges, but not the edges of tiles the edges of tree's or graphs. You can see them as connections. In the display method you can see he appends a "|", " ", or "_" based on N,E,S,W.

He uses bit operators for this which makes this very confusing imho. Each N, E, S, W gets a bit value as a int. I do not know much about binary but the & operator compares two bit values and returns a bit where both both on the same position are 1. So 1001 & 1100 = 1000 since only the first is 1 in both bits. Anyway what I think he does here is checking if there is a connection from the grid position to the E(ast) or S(outh).

Since I have no idea what is exactly going on with the bit thing we can use his display method to draw it correctly. But since he is only building east and west tiles we can create a simple method for that. We also need a tileSize.

```
int tileSize = 10;

//Method for drawing a east wall tile position x, y
private void drawEastWall(int x, int y)
{    
    shapeRenderer.line(
    x * tileSize + tileSize,
    y * tileSize, 
    x * tileSize + tileSize,
    y * tileSize + tileSize
    );
}
//Method for drawing a south wall on tile position x, y
private void drawSouthWall(int x, int y)
{
    shapeRenderer.line(
    x * tileSize, 
    y * tileSize,
    x * tileSize + tileSize,
    y * tileSize
    );
}
```

Now replace the "_" = south wall and "|" = east wall with our new methods.

```
for (int y = 0; y < mHeight; y++) {
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    sb.append('|');
    drawEastWall(0, y);
    //We did not loop x yet so we just filled 0 here.

    for (int x = 0; x < mWidth; x++) {
        int cell = mGrid[y][x];
        if (cell == 0)
            sb.append(' ');
//This represents no walls so we leave it
        if ((cell & S) != 0) { 
            sb.append(' ');
        } else {
            sb.append('_'); //South wall
            drawSouthWall(x,y);
        }

        if ((cell & E) != 0) {
            if (((cell | mGrid[y][x+1]) & S) != 0) {
                sb.append(' ');
            } else {
                sb.append('_'); //south wall
                drawSouthWall(x, y);
            }
        } else {
            sb.append('|'); //East wall
            drawEastWall(x, y);
        }
    }
Gdx.app.log(TAG, sb.toString());
}
```

That's all! If you are actually calling this in the draw method you should remove all the string builder things and not output it each frame. Double for loops are used very often to draw a 2d tileset. Here is some example to make it clearer.

```
//The following represents a 10 x 10 grid. We traverse the grid from left to right and top to bottom.
        for (int y = 0; y < 10; y++)
        {
            for (int x = 0; x < 10; x++)
            {
                //Here we could draw or change the grid or tile map. I prefer using the word tile map.

                //if x = 4 and our tileWidth = 10 we now we should start drawing at x: 40 to x:50.
                //when x = 5 we start drawing at x:50 to x:60, we do the same for y.

                //Most of the time we have some kind of 2d array that holds a tile class.
                //In a loop like this we can initialize and alter it
                tileMap[x][y] = new Tile(waterTexture);
                tileMap[x][y].tileTexture = forestTexture;

            }
        }
```